# If I use object.getElementsByTagName(tagName) in a for statement

Tags: javascript, dom, nodelist

If I use `object.getElementsByTagName(tagName)` in a for statement,

```
for (index = 0; index < object.getElementsByTagName(tagName).length; index++) {
object.getElementsByTagName(tagName)[index].property = value;
}
```

Does the browser instantiate a new nodeList object for every pass through the loop, or does the browser simply refer to a single generated list every time; or maybe, it instantiates a list, references the object specified and unloads the list object every pass through the loop?

I've been wondering if its better to store the nodeList object to a variable and reference it when neened.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the browser instantiate a new nodeList object for every pass through the loop or does the browser simply refer to a single generated list every time;

You can test this easily by testing whether two calls to `getElementsByTagName` return the same object:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div') === document.getElementsByTagName('div')
// true
```

It seems that calling this method with the same argument does indeed return the same `NodeList` object (in Firefox and Chrome at least). **It does not generate a new list every time**.

So you might think that calling it in the loop over and over again won't make a difference. However, as I see it, there are multiple reasons why would want to store the list in a variable:

- You have an unnecessary function call in each loop.
- You don't know what actually happens behind the scenes. Even though the same object is returned, the might be procedures running which make sure that the list reflects the current state of the document, which would not happen if you didn't call the function.
- Most importantly: [The DOM specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-A6C9094) doesn't seem to require that the same list is to be returned. That it does in Firefox and Chrome (where I tested it) might just be an implementation detail, so I wouldn't rely on this behavior. In fact, the specification explicitly states to return a *new* list:

  > Return Value: A new NodeList object containing all the matched Elements.

---

> I've been wondering if its better to store the nodeList object to a variable and reference it when needed.

Yes it is. You don't even have to call `getElementsByTagName` again when elements are added or removed because the returned `NodeList` is *live*, i.e. any changes made to the document are directly reflected in the list, without you having it to update explicitly.
Certain operations, like accessing the `length` of the list will also trigger a reevaluation. So, additionally to storing the list in a variable, you might want to cache the length as well:

```
var nodes = object.getElementsByTagName(tagName);

for (var index = 0, l = nodes.length; index < l; index++) {
    nodes[index].property = value;
}
```

This can be very handy or very confusing, depending on what you need. If you only want a list of nodes that exist at the moment the function is called, you have to convert the NodeList to an array:

```
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(object.getElementsByTagName(tagName), 0);
```

Comment: I thought myself that maybe it would return the same list as some sort of, perhaps, browser-specific implementation tuning, but I guess its true that you would want to avoid the uneccesary procedures accociated with the method call.

Comment: Does referencing the nodelist stored in a variable cause re-evaluation as well? Perhaps it would be more process-efficient to store the nodeList to an array (I didn't know you could do that, by the way, that might serve useful in itself), but I guess it would come down to the efficiency of the process of converting it vs. the evaluation of the state of the document. What do you think about that?

Comment: I don't know exactly *when* a NodeList is refreshed, i.e. either when the modification happens or the list is accessed. Both have advantages and disadvantages. I wouldn't worry too much about the performance difference between reevaluation and converting to an array though. Since all of this things are implemented natively, they are going to be quite fast anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This is way better code for the reasons listed below:

```
var elems = object.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
for (var index = 0, len = elems.length; index < len; index++) {
    elems[index].property = value;
}
```

1. It cannot ever call `getElementsByTagName()` more than once.  It only fetches the nodeList once.
2. It doesn't rely on any specific browser implementation in order to be efficient.
3. It preloads the length of the nodeList so even that isn't refetched each time through the loop.
4. It's just a safer way to make your code efficient.
5. Safer code makes the implementation questions you asked irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is generating a new list each time.
But this code will work as `index` is changing every run.

It is a good practice to first save node list in some `var`:

```
var elements = object.getElementsByTagName(tagName);

for (index = 0; index < elements; index++) {
        elements[index].property = value;
}
```

you can see your aproach as:

```
var index = 0;

while(index<object.getElementsByTagName(tagName))
{
  elements[index].property = value;
  index++;
}
```

Comment: *Your browser is generating a new list each time.* This doesn't match with my observations.

Comment: `for(var i=0; i<10;i++) { if(object.getElementsByTagName('someId')>0) { //do someThing;} };` Here condition in `if` will be execute each time, so method in it will be called each time. That happens with fore loop.

Comment: Of course the method will be called each time, but that doesn't mean that the method returns a new list every time.

Comment: If by some async ajax call, a new `tag` appended mean while then?

Comment: I guess you mean `index < elements.length`.

Comment: While the loop is running, no other code, like an Ajax success callback can be executed. Second of all, since `NodeList`'s are already live, I assume that it would still return the same list object. You can easily test this with `var list = document.getElementsByTagName('div'); document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')); console.log(list === document.getElementsByTagName('div'));`

Comment: `elements.length` will return same list but, `object.getElementsByTagName('someId')` will not.

Comment: @FelixKling, mean `document.getElementsByTagName('div'); ` list if initialized in `for` loop, in that case, no changes will effect that list. Its state will remain constant?

Comment: Unless the document is modified in the loop, yes.

Comment: So, it indeed does reference the same list every pass through the loop, but calls the method every time as well; so, theoretically, it would be better to simply refer to the nodeList object stored to a variable to avoid the procedure call and accociated procecures?

Comment: @FelixKling if document is modified in for loop than, a list with added new element becomes part of for loop and all further iteration and processing done with new added element list. This true that list will not be affected from outside changes, because they cannot be done mean while.

Comment: So, if you wanted to do something with the element added to the documenet, for (blah=0; blah < getelementsbytagname().length; blah++) { getelementsbytagname[blah].insertAfter(createNode()).property = value }, it would be better to use the re-evualuation property of the method call or variable-oriented nodelist reference than to store the list as an array object in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

this test shows that it first gets the array calculates the length each time!

```
var testObj = {
    getArray: function () {
        console.log( 'getting array' );
        return this._array;
    },
    _array: ['a','b','c']
};

for ( var index = 0; index < testObj.getArray().length; index++ ){
    document.write( testObj.getArray()[index] );
}
```

I would either store the elements first, and reference it's .length each time, or just store the length in a variable :)

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect it to do? Read your mind? Did you expect the JS processor to have the semantic information that `object.getElementsByTagName(tagName)` will (probably) return the same value each time it is called, and is thus "loop-invariant" and can thus be hoisted out of the loop (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion)?

Perhaps you imagined that the browser is somehow "caching" the list of all elements with a particular tagname under the element, and then just returning the same list in subsequent calls? Although it's hard to tell what a browser is doing inside without looking at the code, it may not be, or one browser might be and another browser not. Even if the browser does cache the result, granted that any performance hit is likely to be minor in the overall scheme of things, calling the API again and again will always be much less efficient that referring to a variable that's already set. And it is not impossible that what you do with each element of the nodelist, such as setting a property, could cause the cache to be reset.

As a minor point, assuming the list is created over and over again, it is not then "unloaded"; there is no such concept in JS. In technical terms, its status would be "just left sitting there". It will be garbage collected soon enough.

So yes, by all means call `getElementsByTagName` just once. Actually, you can call it once at the beginning of your program (assuming there's just one object and tagname you're interested in), since it returns a "live" list. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getElementsByTagName.

Comment: Well, other users did say that, at last some browsers (maybe implementation-variant), did in fact refer to the same nodelist object every time. I did think that it was probably more process-efficient to avoid the procedure call every pass through the loop, but was probably not really a very big issue anyway, not for common applications. I guess if I were programming with process and memory-efficiency in mind, it would be useful to know.